# Can I convert an image from CMYK to RGB in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, images, conversion, colors, preview

Is there a way to convert a JPEG from CMYK to RGB, using Preview or any other tool built into Mac OS X?

I see I can go to <kbd>Tools | Assign Profile…</kbd>  and select from a long list of options, including Generic CMYK Profile, but there's no RGB option.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found three ways to do it.

1. Open the image with [ColorSync](https://support.apple.com/guide/colorsync-utility/welcome/mac).
2. Use the <kbd>Apply ColorSync Profile to Images</kbd> action in Automator.
3. Use [sips](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sips.1.html) (thanks NSD) and supply the <kbd>--matchTo</kbd> argument. I wrote a shell script to convert an image using the Generic RGB Profile.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then
    cat >&2 <<EOF
usage:
    $0 filename
    $0 source-file destination-file

    Converts an image to RGB color space. The first form manipulates
    the file in-place.
EOF
    exit 1
fi           

SOURCE_FILE=$1

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    DESTINATION_FILE=$SOURCE_FILE
else
    DESTINATION_FILE=$2
fi

sips \
    --matchTo '/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/Generic RGB Profile.icc' \
    "$SOURCE_FILE" \
    --out "$DESTINATION_FILE"
```

Comment: ColorSync link is dead, but otherwise good answer!

Comment: To clarify the ColorSync option, I succeeded in converting my PSD file using the "Match to Profile" menu in the bottom-left corner in ColorSync 4.14.0

Answer (score 1):

On my machine (10.6.2), two RGB profiles are offered: "Adobe RGC (1998)" and "Generic RGB Profile".
Gimp (free) can do the conversion, too.

Comment: I get those options as well when I open an image that's already RGB.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have the RGB colorsync profiles, so I imported the files into iPhoto and then exported them again. The exported photos were in RGB. Voila

Answer (score 1):

It's really easy. You don’t need to do any of these steps. In the Mac OS X “Preview” app, just go under Tools, Match to Profile, and under “Color Model” select RGB. The ColorSync Profile will change automatically. Save, and it’s done!

Comment: In what program?

Comment: "Preview". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preview_(Mac_OS)

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason I wasn't able to change the color mode with Preview and the Tools section.  My needs my have been simpler, but I ended up just opening the image in Preview on my large external monitor and then using Skitch to take a screenshot of it.  It fit my needs, it may fit yours.

Answer (score 0):

See this: [sips(1) [osx man page]](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/sips/)

Answer (score 0):

If you have [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) installed on your machine, you can do this in Terminal.

For `image.jpg`:

```
convert -colorspace RGB image.jpg newImage.jpg
```

`newImage.jpg` will be the same image in RGB space.

Comment: True, but without assigning profiles to CMYK input and RGB output the result will show colors that are far away from any acceptable conversion algorithm.